# Angular CLI - New Project not launching in browser

Tags: angular, npm

I created a brand new project using Angular CLI. After issuing command NPM start, the application did not launch the browser. Following is the error in log file:-

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.11.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle ccc@0.0.0~prestart: ccc@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle ccc@0.0.0~start: ccc@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle ccc@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle ccc@0.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;E:\CrossCompCommunication\CCC\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Siddarth\AppData\Roaming\npm;E:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin
9 verbose lifecycle ccc@0.0.0~start: CWD: E:\CrossCompCommunication\CCC
10 silly lifecycle ccc@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'ng serve' ]
11 silly lifecycle ccc@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle ccc@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: ccc@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid ccc@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd E:\CrossCompCommunication\CCC
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.3.9600
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v8.11.1
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error ccc@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the ccc@0.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Any inputs would help.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

The ELIFECYCLE error meant the program unexpectedly stopped. This can have various reasons, like if you try to run the npm command again on another terminal (cmd). Make sure that you don't have any other instance running up in the same port.

Try to clean your cache with: `npm cache clean` with Administrator/root and delete your node_modules, after this steps, try to install your packages again with npm install --save

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to update Node recently?

Either way, it may help to delete your `node_modules` folder, update the CLI (`npm install -g @angular/cli`), and reinstall (`npm install`).

Good luck! It always sucks when things don't work!

Comment: I did that but the problem persist. It sucks because it slowed me down :). I moved the code to another project and everything works fine. No clue what was missing.I removed the node_modules folder too.  Any  way thanks for sharing your inputs.